# Observer<T>.OnError's assumptions seem to be inconsistent with Stubs.Throw

Tags: system.reactive

One of the overloads on IObservable<T>.Subscribe is

```cs
public static IDisposable Subscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<T> onNext)
```

Internally, this creates and registers an `AnoymousObserver<T>` on the IObservable. The unspecified `onError` parameter is set to `Stubs.Throw` which is a simple lambda that rethrows the exception passed in.

Internally, the observers for an IObservable are all contained in a single instance of type Observer. This is the code in `Observer<T>.OnError`

```cs
public void OnError(Exception error)
{
    foreach (var observer in _observers.Data)
        observer.OnError(error);
}
```

Since Stubs.Throw throws the exception, the exception from that observer's OnError passes up through the foreach loop and other observers in _observers.Data never have their OnError called. The exception itself is swallowed somewhere inside Rx.

It seems to me that either Observer<T>.OnError should wrap observer.OnError in a try-catch, or Stubs.Throw should swallow the exception instead of throwing it. By not passing an onError parameter, the user of IObservable.Subscribe wishes the error to be ignored only for that Subscribe. The other subscribers registered with their own onError callbacks should be unaffected.

(I already filed a [bug](http://rx.codeplex.com/workitem/12) on Codeplex but the tracker looks deserted, so I thought I'd ask on SO too to see if I'm understanding this correctly.)

---

Update: Asti's answer is correct. In the discussion on the linked bug report, davedev gave an analogy with IEnumerable, and how the default of throwing the exception unhandled is the equivalent of the default of iterating an IEnumerable without a catch block.

If the observable determines that a particular exception should not be considered fatal, it should not communicate this using OnError. OnError is not guaranteed to be executed since calling it implies something went seriously wrong with the observable in the first place. Instead, the observable can be defined as an IObservable<[Either](http://rxx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70579#1055656)<T, Exception>> (example usage in [Observable2.Retry](http://rxx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70579#1055697)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the expected behavior.

`OnError` is not a method to be called to indicate that an exception was thrown on an observer's `OnNext` - it is to denote the abnormal termination of an observable sequence. The default `OnError` implementation will throw the exception as the notification transitions out of the Observable monad.

You will have more clarity on the Rx contract and exception handling if you read the [Rx Design Guidelines](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219). As for error handling along the pipeline, and more `IEnumerable`/`IQueryable`-like behavior, have a look at `SubscribeSafe`.